# How expensive is the jQuery function?

Tags: jquery, performance

On my site I have a huge table with tens of thousands of cells (some of the cells have a class called **myClass1**). Let's say the table has 100000 cells. I can add a new class (**myClass2**) to all cells with class of **myClass1** in one of the following 2 ways:

```
$("#myTable td.myClass1").addClass("myClass2");
```

or I can use .each():

```
$("#myTable td").each(function (i) {
    if ($(this).hasClass("myClass1")) {
        $(this).addClass("myClass2");
    }
});
```

I have read that .each() is fast, but it invokes the jQuery function ($) 2 (per loop iteration) x 100000 times. Even if the 1st method is slower, wouldn't the site take a hit
by invoking $ 200000 times, which would make the 1st method (which invokes $ once) better? Or am I way off here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one will be faster because it uses native css selector support for filtering the element where as the second one we are performing a manual filter.

[Benchmark Profile](http://jsperf.com/native-selector-vs-manual-filter)

Comment: Great answer...thanks for the jsperf to support your answer. Second method is over 40% slower